# How can I get my divs to maintain a consistent height with one another?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a series of scroll links throughout my website and am trying to get them to maintain the same height responsively so when one now has to use two rows the others change height to stay consistent.  I came across a couple solutions on here which I'll get into in a sec.  First let me show you the code.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.full_section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link_frame {
  margin: 7em 0 11em 0;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  display: block;
}
.quarter_section {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link_container {
  float: left;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  display: block;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link {
  width: 77%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  border-radius: 0.44em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.color_style_b_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #888;
  border-width: .11em;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.44);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.88);
}
.color_style_g_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #55ED2B;
  border-width: .11em;
  color: #B5FFB8;
  background-color: rgba(10, 61, 12, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.44);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.88);
}
.color_style_k_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: .11em;
  border-color: #DB3016;
  color: #FFAF69;
  background-color: rgba(102, 0, 0, 0.11);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(214, 73, 34, 0.88);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(214, 73, 34, 0.44);
}
.color_style_j_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: .11em;
  border-color: #633191;
  color: #CD9AFC;
  background-color: rgba(67, 3, 150, 0.11);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.88);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.44);
}
```

```html
<div id="Personal_Strengths_link_frame" class="full_section  Pro_Qual_s_link_frame">

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_k_1" href="#html">
                Back To Top
            </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_b_1" href="#Specialty_Practices_frame">
                Specialty Practices
            </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_g_1" href="#Industries_Served_frame">
            Industries I've Served
            </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_j_1" href="#Tools_of_Choice_frame">
                My Tools Of Choice
            </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/2xcuq6rs/3/

### Here's the few solutions I've tried

Ok, so the first solution I found was to change the containing element's display to table and the elements inside of it to table-cell.  In my instance I changed `.Pro_Qual_s_link_frame` to have the display of `table` and the `.Pro_Qual_s_link` to have the display of `table-cell`

I did this because the `.Pro_Qual_s_link_container` is there as part of the framework to keep everything tamed responsively.  This didn't work, it also made the link as big as the Pro_Qual_s_link_container element.  I tried playing with the height and width to see if I could get it to work, nothing happened.

Next I found a solution on here suggesting using flex.  I set that up like this

```
.Pro_Qual_s_link_frame{
    margin: 7em 0 11em 0;
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    display: flex;
}

.Pro_Qual_s_link{
    width: 77%;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    border-radius: 0.44em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Not only did this not work, but it seems to have canceled out the width and padding.  When I scale the size down I see 2 extra boxes pop up on each element like it's creating a new box for the second row of text.  I played around more with various different settings like switching from percentages to em and it still didn't effect it.

I played around with the display settings on the 3 elements to see if I could come up with a combo of the two solutions that worked and nothing panned out.  Did I do something wrong or miss a step somewhere?  Or do I need a different solution for my particular instance?

Comment: i thing u need to add min-height. .Pro_Qual_s_link{min-height:38px; .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using display-table instead of flexbox (flexbox is great but if you need IE compatibility, you can't use it) :

**HTML**

```
<div id="Personal_Strengths_link_frame" class="full_section  Pro_Qual_s_link_frame">

    <div class="Pro_Qual_s_link_container color_style_k_1">
        <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link" href="#html">
            Back To Top
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="Pro_Qual_s_link_container color_style_b_1">
        <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link" href="#Specialty_Practices_frame">
            Specialty Practices
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="Pro_Qual_s_link_container color_style_g_1">
        <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link" href="#Industries_Served_frame">
            Industries I've Served
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="Pro_Qual_s_link_container color_style_j_1">
        <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link" href="#Tools_of_Choice_frame">
            My Tools Of Choice
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: #000;
}

.full_section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.Pro_Qual_s_link_frame {
    margin: 7em 0 11em 0;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 30px;
}

.Pro_Qual_s_link_container {
    border-radius: 0.44em;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-width: .11em;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    width: 25%;
}

.Pro_Qual_s_link {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.color_style_b_1 {
    border-color: #888;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.11);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.44);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.88);
}

.color_style_g_1 {
    border-color: #55ED2B;
    color: #B5FFB8;
    background-color: rgba(10, 61, 12, 0.11);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.44);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.88);
}

.color_style_k_1 {
    border-color: #DB3016;
    color: #FFAF69;
    background-color: rgba(102, 0, 0, 0.11);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(214, 73, 34, 0.88);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(214, 73, 34,  0.44);
}

.color_style_j_1 {
    border-color: #633191;
    color: #CD9AFC;
    background-color: rgba(67, 3, 150, 0.11);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.88);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.44);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xcuq6rs/5/)**

Comment: you linked the same fiddle as linked by the OP.

Comment: The fork must not have worked properly then. I'll create a new one as soon as fiddle.net answers...

Comment: You should click on `update` button in fiddle. Anyway, I did that and edited your post.

Comment: That's what I did. And right now I can't display any page from fiddle.net.

Comment: Might be problem at your side. works fine here though.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly.  I had to mess with it a bit to get it to go with the flow of how I have my classes purposed, but it works none the less.  I never thought to use the border spacing lol.

Answer (score 3):

You had some weird margins etc with your solution which made it not work with flex. Here's a working example using flex.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.full_section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link_frame {
  margin: 7em 0 11em 0;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
.quarter_section {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link_container {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  display: block;
}
.Pro_Qual_s_link {
  width: 77%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  border-radius: 0.44em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.color_style_b_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #888;
  border-width: .11em;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.44);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.88);
}
.color_style_g_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-color: #55ED2B;
  border-width: .11em;
  color: #B5FFB8;
  background-color: rgba(10, 61, 12, 0.11);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.44);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(137, 237, 55, 0.88);
}
.color_style_k_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: .11em;
  border-color: #DB3016;
  color: #FFAF69;
  background-color: rgba(102, 0, 0, 0.11);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(214, 73, 34, 0.88);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(214, 73, 34, 0.44);
}
.color_style_j_1 {
  border-style: ridge;
  border-width: .11em;
  border-color: #633191;
  color: #CD9AFC;
  background-color: rgba(67, 3, 150, 0.11);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.88);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3em rgba(140, 0, 255, 0.44);
}
```

```html
<div id="Personal_Strengths_link_frame" class="full_section  Pro_Qual_s_link_frame">

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_k_1" href="#html">
            Back To Top
        </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_b_1" href="#Specialty_Practices_frame">
            Specialty Practices
        </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_g_1" href="#Industries_Served_frame">
            Industries I've Served
        </a>
  </div>

  <div class="quarter_section Pro_Qual_s_link_container">
    <a class="Pro_Qual_s_link color_style_j_1" href="#Tools_of_Choice_frame">
            My Tools Of Choice
        </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/dh0jbwou/